# NHibernate criteria join over many enum values

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I've a single class named `User` and in this class a collection of `UserRole` enum values.

```
public class User {
    ...
    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; private set; }
    ...
}

[Flags]
public enum UserRole {
    Beginner = 1,
    Advanced = 2,
    Expert = 4,
    Admin = 8
}
```

The `User` to `UserRole` relationship is a many-to-many relationship and implemented with three tables (tblUser, tblRole, and tblUserRole having userId and roleId only). The HBM is as follows:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-lazy="false">
   <class name="User, SampleDll" table="tblUser">
   ...
   <bag name="UserRoles" table="tblUserRole" cascade="all-delete-orphan" fetch="join">
      <key column="UserId"/>
      <element column="RoleId" type="UserRole, SampleDll" />      
   </bag> 
   ...
   </class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now I want to create a criteria in which has the same sematics as

```
select u.* from tblUser u 
left join tblUserRole ur on ur.UserId = u.UserId
where ur.RoleId = @USER_ROLE
```

Is it possible to realize such a criteria (either using queryOver or a detached criteria) without having a seperate mapping file for `UserRole` enum?

Thanks in advance for hints.

Mrks

Answer (score 0):

you already have a flags enum that is basicly already a collection of values. For that you dont even need the tables UserRoles and Roles, just a simple column in User would be enough

```
[Flags]
public enum UserRoles {
    Beginner = 1,
    Advanced = 2,
    Expert = 4,
    Admin = 8
}

public virtual UserRoles Roles { get; private set; }

<property name="Roles" column="UserRoles"/>
```

---

When you really want something like:

```
public class User {
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> Roles { get; private set; }
    ...
}

public class UserRole {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

then

```
<bag name="Roles" table="tblUserRole" cascade="none"> <!-- none because Roles are somewhat static not per user -->
   <key column="UserId"/>
   <many-to-many column="RoleId" class="UserRole, SampleDll" />      
</bag>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="UserRole" table="Roles">
    <id name="Id"/>
    <!--additional properties-->
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```